# Disable link, after it is clicked

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tabs

So, I have some links in my page (< a > type), marked with different ID-s. They have those attributes:

1. id - the unique id of each link
2. href - the URL, that will open in new tab /!important -> The link needs to be opened in new tab!/
3. target="_blank" - for the link to open in new tab

So, the links look like:

```
<a id="a1" href="thelink" target="_Blank">Link1</a>
<a id="a2" href="thelink" target="_Blank">Link2</a>
<a id="a3" href="thelink" target="_Blank">Link3</a>
etc..
```

I want when one link is clicked, the URL to open in a new tab, and the link in the original page to be disabled, but not that way:

```
<a id="a3" href="#" target="_Blank">Link1</a
```

I tried using onclick to remove the "href" attribute and onclick to empty the "href" attribute but the link doesnt open, as the onclick fires first and removes the "href" element, before the link opens in new tab and the effect is not the one that i want.
Got some Ideas guys?

Comment: If you remove the href attribute, the A element is no longer a link, it's an anchor which has a different default style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
 <a id="a3" href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="a(this);">Link3</a>
 <a id="a4" href="http://google.com"  onclick="a(this);">Link4</a>
 <a id="a5" href="http://wikipedia.org"  onclick="a(this);">Link5</a>

   <script>
      function a(t) {
        var href = t.getAttribute("href");
        if(href==null || href=="") return;
        window.open(href,'_blank');
        t.removeAttribute("href");
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: The value of the href attribute is a string, so `href == null` will always be false. You might have meant `if (href == '')`.

Comment: For me it works just fine. I tasted it on chrome. Just put javascript code after html tags.

Comment: I tested it on chrome too, but it doesnt work :(.. If i have onmouseover and onmouseout attributes, does that changesthe javascript effect?

Comment: Just copy and paste code above in empty file between <HTML> </HTML> tags. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("a1").onclick=function() {
    setTimout(function() {document.getElementById("a1").disabled=true;},10)
  }
}
```

Comment: HTML5 doesn't seem to mention a disabled property for [*A elements*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through events using a class name as an indicator

http://jsfiddle.net/pyQV2/

In this example I added every link a class, just to indicate the function to target it. Then, on page load I attach an `onclick` event to each link.

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('notclicked');

for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function(e) {
        if (e.target.className == 'notclicked')
            e.target.className = 'clicked';
        else {
            if (e.preventDefault)
                e.preventDefault();
            else /* for IE */
                e.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If it has the old class, just change it for future clicks. If it has the new class, just stop the event.